# Find Duplicate records from a table one after another in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, phpmyadmin

I want to find duplicates records in a table.

```
 public function duplicate_records() {
       $sql = " select * from tbloptions where name in (select name from tbloptions group by name having COUNT(*)>1)";
        $result = $this->db->query($sql);
        $row = $result->result();
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($row);
    }
```

I wrote the above query and I'm getting the following output:-

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => dateformat
            [value] => d-m-Y|%d-%m-%Y
            [autoload] => 1
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => companyname
            [value] => 01Crypto.com
            [autoload] => 1
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 316
            [name] => dateformat
            [value] => d-m-Y|%d-%m-%Y
            [autoload] => 1
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 317
            [name] => dateformat
            [value] => d-m-Y|%d-%m-%Y
            [autoload] => 1
        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 318
            [name] => companyname
            [value] => 01Crypto.com
            [autoload] => 1
        )

)
```

So, In the output `[name] => dateformat` comes 3 times and `[name] => companyname` comes 2 times.

**Edit:-**

I want the following output:-

```
[0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => dateformat
            [value] => d-m-Y|%d-%m-%Y
            [autoload] => 1
        )
[2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 316
            [name] => dateformat
            [value] => d-m-Y|%d-%m-%Y
            [autoload] => 1
        )
[3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 317
            [name] => dateformat
            [value] => d-m-Y|%d-%m-%Y
            [autoload] => 1
        )
[1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => companyname
            [value] => 01Crypto.com
            [autoload] => 1
        )
[4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 318
            [name] => companyname
            [value] => 01Crypto.com
            [autoload] => 1
        )
```

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As my understanding, you need response something this.

```
Array (
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => companyname
            [value] => 01Crypto.com
            [autoload] => 1
        )
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 318
            [name] => companyname
            [value] => 01Crypto.com
            [autoload] => 1
        )
    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => dateformat
            [value] => d-m-Y|%d-%m-%Y
            [autoload] => 1
        )
    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 316
            [name] => dateformat
            [value] => d-m-Y|%d-%m-%Y
            [autoload] => 1
        )
    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 317
            [name] => dateformat
            [value] => d-m-Y|%d-%m-%Y
            [autoload] => 1
        )
)
```

If I'm right then you can try below given example. That will help you.

```
public function duplicate_records() {
   $sql = " select *, GROUP_CONCAT(id) as ids from tbloptions where name in (select name from tbloptions group by name having COUNT(*)>1) group by name order by name";
    $result = $this->db->query($sql);
    $row = $result->result();
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($row);
}
```

Or if I'm wrong then please share output which you need. I will update my answer.

Comment: @AlekStephanok It seems both of the array's are same. which you provided before and after update. please clear.

Comment: You will see in the desired output [name] => dateformat is coming 3 times and then [name] => companyname is coming.....

Comment: yes, I checked. if you will add order by on name column then same name fields will coming together.

Comment: @AlekStephanok If this answer is helpful for you, then upvote this and also click on check to verify. That will be very appreciated.